# How to set dpi of image to 300 in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to change the image DPI to 300 for existing image in PHP.

I have that image in database and i am getting it through PHP.

Code for getting image as follows:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring ( base64_decode($matches[2]) );

imagepng($image, $imageFile);
```

I want to set DPI of above image to 300.

I am using Zend framework for it.

How can i set it using PHP?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use imagemagic to do the job

```
$oResamp = new Resampler;
$image = $oResamp->resample($source, $height, $width, 300);
```